# Unable to run unicorn app server on a vagrant box

Tags: ruby, git, ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra

I have a vagrant box on which RVM is already installed with ruby 2.0.0-p247. I have packaged the vagrant box and using that box as a base box.
Now I am trying to git clone a github private repo and start the unicorn app server, chef is errors out,here is the output of the error

```
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find chef (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.7.7, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
==> default:    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
==> default:    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
==> default:    from /usr/bin/chef-solo:22:in `<main>'
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I am not able to debug the issue. Its ubuntu 14.04 box. Kindly help me out

Comment: Looks like script can not find chef installation. Try to install chef yourself: `gem install chef` and run the script again.

Comment: You have environment variables set by RVM which override chef embedded ruby paths. Try `env - chef-client` (you may need to use full path) to run it without env variables and let chef defines its own. should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [vagrant-omnibus](https://github.com/opscode/vagrant-omnibus) plugin to install Chef. This will give Chef its own isolated Ruby environment separate from your RVM setup.

Comment: Is it not already OP case, as we see a `/opt/chef/embedded/...` path in the error ? (Really asking if vagrant-omnibus would fix that)

Comment: If so, I'm guessing something screwed with `/usr/bin/chef-solo` so it no longer points at the omnibus Ruby correctly or removed gems from the omnibus Ruby.

Comment: RVM does dick with $GEM_HOME and $GEM_PATH sometimes, which could do this.

Comment: Yes, and I'm unsure, but I think the GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH takes precedence over static informations from chef ruby. Getting rid of them (with `env -`) should not harm chef and solve the problem (at least it does not break chef run on my boxes (ubuntu 12.04, chef 11.16.4).